# How to find an element in HTML string and change an attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This seems to be a very simple question but I've been at it for a couple of hours trying to make it work.

I have a string like:

```
var myhtml = '<div id="wrapper"><div id="full" width="800px"></div></div>';
```

I need to find my div `#full`, remove it's `"*width*"` attribute and then use myhtml with the updated version.

I'm using this in jQuery:

```
var newhtml = $(myhtml).filter("#full").removeAttr("width");
console.log(newhtml );
```

Expecting this: `<div id="wrapper"><div id="full"></div></div>`

But it returns `"<div id="full"></div>"` and not the whole variable.

Comment: Why not target it with $('#full')?

Comment: you would need to use a documentFragment if you want to mount <HTML> and/or <BODY> tags.

Comment: @dandavis edited my question to make it clear. The problem is not with HTML and BODY tags, is with it's content. Please check the new version of my question.

Austin Kilduff: mmm sorry couldn't understand your idea :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find("#full")` to select the element then remove attribute. The original object retains the value.

```js
var myhtml = $('<div id="wrapper"><div id="full" width="800px"></div></div>');
var newhtml = myhtml.find("#full").removeAttr("width");
console.log($(myhtml)[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```